# Пагинация для OkHttp

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Всем привет! В своем приложении я использую API которое предоставляет мне 100 записей на 1 страницу. Получение API реализовано через OkHttp. Чтобы получить доступ ко второй странице нужно добавить в конец ссылки `?page=2`. В API указывается сколько всего записей и страниц:

```
"pagination":{
     "total":1565
     "count":100
     "per_page":100
     "current_page":1
     "total_pages":16
     "links":{
         "next":"https://link?page=2"
     }
 }
```

Показ записей в приложении реализован с помощью `RecyclerView`, файлов Adapter и Item. И все это в `Fragment`, а не `Activity`. Как мне после выгрузки 100 записей добавить в конец ссылки `?page=2` и чтобы новые записи добавлялись ниже старых в тот-же `RecyclerView`? Я знаю, как можно реализовать кнопку "показать 2 страницу" и чтобы она передавала данные в новый фрагмент... Но я хочу чтобы все записи были на одной странице. Большое Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Вот какой ответ придумал я, может кто-то предложит что-то получше)

int pages = 1;
int current_page;
int total_pages;
Content content;

private class Content extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
...
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
             ...
             OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
             Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https:link.com/&page=" + pages)
                    .get();
             current_page = Jarray_pagination_p.getInt("current_page");
             total_pages = Jarray_pagination_p.getInt("total_pages");
             ...
             }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (current_page != total_pages){
            ++pages;
            content = new Content();
            content.execute();
        }
    }
}
```